# Test fails when run together but passes alone

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, rspec, integration-testing, rspec-rails

I am new to RSPEC and am testing the controllers.
Sometimes it happens that the test passes alone like

```
rspec spec/controllers/controller_name_spec.rb
```

it passes but when I run :-

```
rspec spec
```

the test fails, same test that passed earlier.

What can be the reason, is it related to scalability of rspec or an application specific issue.
As I found same issue with integration tests also.
Rails -v => 3.2.11
Ruby -v => 1.9.2p320
Rspec-rails version =>  2.13.0
rspec version => 2.13.0

eg:-

Test case :-

```
it "should do ##something##" do
   plans=Plan.pluck(:id)
   plans.delete(@user.subscription.plan.id)
   @user.subscription.stripe_customer_token= "cus_1l9m6CicQEXZJ0"
   @user.save
   get 'apply_change_account', {:subscription=>{:plan_id=>plans.sample}}
   flash.now[:success].should_not be_nil
   response.should redirect_to dashboard_manage_accounts_path
 end
```

Response error message :-

```
1) DashboardController Dashboard should do ##something##
    Failure/Error: flash.now[:success].should_not be_nil
      expected: not nil
           got: nil
    # ./spec/controllers/dashboard_controller_spec.rb:119:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: test code and fail messages please.

Comment: @BillyChan edited and added the test case with it's response.

Comment: The only reason I can think about is the database not got cleared during the tests. Maybe you can check if that is true and then install database_cleaner gem.

Comment: @BillyChan Already using that in "config.after(:each) do" block with database cleaner.

Comment: although while debugging I got to know that flash.now[:success] was present but still the error prevails when running "rspec spec"

Answer (score 1):

Try add `flash.clear` in before block for every test related to flash.

This may or may not solve the problem, but it's essential to test flash related item to avoid flash object been polluted.